# Retain http method on redirect

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I wrote localisation helper in [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) which checks whether `en`, `fr` or another local is in the URI. 
If no locale is supplied `config("app.locale")` should be prepended to the original URI and a redirect should be made to this new URI. I.e. `/user` should be redirected too `/en/user`.

I am currently trying to resolve this problem by using:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $langSegment = $request->segment(1);

    // if first segment is language parameter then go on
    if (strlen($langSegment) == 2 && ($langSegment == 'en' || $langSegment == 'fr')) {
        App::setLocale($langSegment);
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        $newURL=url(config("app.locale") . "/" . implode("/",$request->segments()));       
        return redirect($newURL);
    }

}
```

This works fine for most request unless the method is `POST` and there is no `$language` set. When this is the case the user is redirect but the method is changed to a `POST` request.

I also tried changing my redirect to

```
return redirect()->route('routeName', $request->all(), 302, ['method','POST'])
```

But this also doesn't work.

Comment: Lovely question, while I do not have an answer right now I do think you will get in the right direction when you are looking at the [HTTP status code 307](https://httpstatuses.com/307), maybe in combination with [custom headers](https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/14/laravel-5-performing-http-redirects-with-redirect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some testing with regards to the [HTTP status code 307](https://httpstatuses.com/307).

Let me first describe my test setup, I created the following routes:

```
Route::get("/help", 'HelpController@index');
Route::post("/post", 'HelpController@post');
Route::post("/redirected", 'HelpController@redirected');
```

The `HelpController` contained the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HelpController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('help');
    }

    public function post(){
        return redirect('/redirected', 307);
    }

    public function redirected(){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```

and `help.blade.php` was a very basic form namely:

```
<form method="post" action="/post">
    @csrf
    <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

I am glad to report that **a 307 return code does successfully keep the POST method.**

I.e. when I went to the `/help` url and pressed the "Go" button I saw the "Success" message as expected.

What does this mean for me you might ask?

Well we can solve your problems with a very simple change:

```
return redirect($newURL);
```

becomes

```
return redirect($newURL, 307);
```

Wasn't that easy in the end?

Furthermore as you can see in my test setup this also keeps the crsf protection which is a definite plus from a security standpoint.